# Binding list to params in Pandas read_sql_query with other params

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc

I've been trying to test various methods for making my code to run. To begin with, I have this list:

`member_list = [111,222,333,444,555,...]`

I tried to pass it into this query:

```py
query = pd.read_sql_query(
"""
select member id
    ,yearmonth
from queried_table
where yearmonth between ? and ?
    and member_id in ?
""", db2conn, params = [201601, 201603, member_list])
```

However, I get an error that says:

> 'Invalid parameter type.  param-index=2 param-type=list', 'HY105'

So I looked around and tried using formatted strings:

```py
query = pd.read_sql_query(
"""
select member id
    ,yearmonth
from queried_table
where yearmonth between ? and ?
    and member_id in (%s)
""" % ','.join(['?']*len(member_list), db2conn, params = [201601, 201603, tuple(member_list)])
```

Now, I get the error:

> 'The SQL contains 18622 parameter markers, but 3 parameters were supplied', 'HY000'

because it's looking to fill in all the `?` placeholders in the formatted string.

So, ultimately, is there a way to somehow evaluate the list and pass each individual element to bind to the `?` or is there another method I could use to get this to work?

Btw, I'm using `pyodbc` as my connector.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Break this up into three parts to help isolate the problem and improve readability:

1. Build the SQL string
2. Set parameter values
3. Execute [pandas.read_sql_query](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html)

---

### Build SQL

First ensure `?` placeholders are being set correctly. Use [str.format](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#format-examples) with [str.join](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [len](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#len) to dynamically fill in `?`s based on `member_list` length. Below examples assume 3 `member_list` elements.

#### Example

```
member_list = (1,2,3)
sql = """select member_id, yearmonth
         from queried_table
         where yearmonth between {0} and {0}
         and member_id in ({1})"""
sql = sql.format('?', ','.join('?' * len(member_list)))
print(sql)
```

#### Returns

```
select member_id, yearmonth
from queried_table
where yearmonth between ? and ?
and member_id in (?,?,?)
```

---

### Set Parameter Values

Now ensure parameter values are organized into a *flat* tuple

#### Example

```
# generator to flatten values of irregular nested sequences,
# modified from answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python
def flatten(l):
    for el in l:
        try:
            yield from flatten(el)
        except TypeError:
            yield el

params = tuple(flatten((201601, 201603, member_list)))
print(params)
```

#### Returns

```
(201601, 201603, 1, 2, 3)
```

---

### Execute

Finally bring the `sql` and `params` values together in the `read_sql_query` call

```
query = pd.read_sql_query(sql, db2conn, params)
```

Comment: The flatten function did it!!! However, I think I just ran into a problem with a parameter cap. Apparently, my member list has 84000+ members, but when I try to dynamically fill in the `?` placeholders for all those members, Python limited to a max of 18,622. Looks like I'm going to have to split my member list to do this. Thanks for you help!

Comment: Happy to help. Since you're working with that many `member_list` values,  will likely get better performance (and fix the parameter limitation) by populating another table then inner join to filter results. [pandas.DataFrame.to_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html#pandas-dataframe-to-sql) might help with table creation.

Comment: For `pymysql` you need a `%s` placeholder, so it should be `','.join(['%s'] * len(member_list))`

Comment: Bryan's answer is awesome! One note though, params is not by default the 3rd argument in pd.read_sql_query, so it only worked when I specified that params=params as such:
pd.read_sql_query(sql, db2conn, params=params) more:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html

Comment: Surely there's a way to achieve this that just lets you pass the list in directly as a param, though, no!?

Answer (score 14):

**WARNING!** Although my proposed solution here works, it is prone to SQL injection attacks.
Therefor, it should **never** be used directly in backend code!
It is only safe for offline analysis.

If you're using python 3.6+ you could also use a formatted string litteral for your query (cf https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498)

```
start, end = 201601, 201603
selected_members = (111, 222, 333, 444, 555)  # requires to be a tuple

query = f"""
    SELECT member_id, yearmonth FROM queried_table
    WHERE yearmonth BETWEEN {start} AND {end}
      AND member_id IN {selected_members}
"""

df = pd.read_sql_query(query, db2conn)
```

Comment: note: 'start' and 'end' might need to be cast as strings depending on the type of the 'yearmonth' column in your DB table...

Comment: While your proposed method will work, it wouldn't be recommended because it would be prone to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: There is indeed a slight risk (but a lot of things would make the query fail anyway). That being said, the proposed solution doesn't provide a whole lot more security (just checking that the past list is enumerable via the usage of join). I think if you take it far enough that might also be prone to injection attacks... Anyway, first it wasn't not clear to me that the query served a front-end directy; second, the responsibility of validating the input should be in a function wrapping that query, not the query string itself...

Comment: Last thing, depending on the DB engine used, you might need to validate the `selected_members` tuple when it's composed of a single element. That's because in python it would print as `(111,)` whereas (at least via psycopg2) the query would only successfully be parsed if it was `(111)`.

Comment: This is a very bad idea and a **major** risk. What if `selected_members` contained `1); drop table Students'; --` ? Parameters eliminate the risk of SQL injection because the parameter values never become part of the query. `doesn't provide a whole lot more security` actually, it does

Comment: Good point Panagiotis! I'll update my answer with a warning message.

And sorry for my past comments, I wasn't conscious on those types of threats back then...

Answer (score -5):

```
query = 'Select count(*) cnt from TBL_DESK_AUDIT  where trunc(DATETIMECREATED) = trunc(sysdate) and DESK_NAME =' + "'"+dataframe_list1[0][0] + "'"
print(query)
df_TBL_DESK_AUDIT = pd.read_sql_query(query, connect);
```