# Running SQL commands through Python containing symbols

Tags: python, sql

I'm trying to run the following code in Python to check various columns in SQL for entries containing the @ symbol:

```
out = pd.read_sql_query('select count(*) from [A].[' + str(Table1) + '] where [' + str(Column1) + '] not like '%@%'', cnxn)
```

The script has a loop which changes the Table1 and Column1 each time it runs. But the "not like '%@%''" part is causing issues. How do I correct this?

When I run it, I get the error

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Try to escape the `'` around the `%@`

Comment: Relevant [binding-list-to-params-in-pandas-read-sql-query-with-other-params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36840438/binding-list-to-params-in-pandas-read-sql-query-with-other-params)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic example to use parameterization to avoid quote escaping or enclosures in SQL. Parameterization is supported in pandas' [`read_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) using *params* argument. And because you require dynamic table and column identifiers, use `str.format` for these items since only literal values can be parameterized but use parameterziation in `LIKE` clause.

Below assumes your DB-API such as `sqlite3` or `pyodbc` uses qmark, `?`, placeholders. Otherwise such as `pymysql`, `psycopg2`, etc. use `%s` or named parameters:

```
query = '''select count(*) 
           from [A].[{tbl}]
           where [{col}] not like ?
        '''
# NOTE USE OF ONE-ITEM TUPLE
out = pd.read_sql(query.format(tbl=str(Table1), col=str(Column1)), cnxn, params=('%@%',))
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not a standard way to build your read_sql_query method, you can try something like this:

```
query = 'select count(*) from ? where ? not like ?'
out = pd.read_sql_query(query, cnxn, params=(table_name, column_name, expression))
```

Comment: This gives the error: : Execution failed on sql 'select count(*) from ? where ? not like ?'

Comment: Can you please provide the full code snippet? It will help me to understand the problem more better.

Comment: query = 'select count(*) from ? where ? not like ?'
out = pd.read_sql_query(query, cnxn, params=(str(dfb1), str(dfb2), str('%@%')))

Comment: Let us assume, the table name is 'user_table' and the column name is 'email'. so the code should be 

table_name = 'user_table'
column_name = 'email'
expression = '\'%@%\''

out = pd.read_sql_query(query, cnxn, params=(table_name, column_name, expression)

Try with this and let me know the result